# I got this error, how can i fix? DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I fix this?
Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Code:

```js
let y = process.openStdin()
y.addListener('data', res => {
    let x = res.toString().trim().split(/ +/g)
    if (!x) return;
    client.channels.cache.get("736725455599697980").send(x.join(" "));
});
```

Comment: The issue is because `x.join(" ")` is returning an empty string or just whitespace. Make sure that the stdin is not empty or just whitespace before sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```js
if (!x) return;
```

---

You should use `x[0]` as your return condition instead of just `x`. An empty array is still an array, and can thus pass your current requirement without issue.

However, `discord.js` cannot send an empty array, which is why you're getting your error.

---

**Quick Demonstration:**

```js
const example = () => {

// even if x is an empty array
let x = [];

// it will still be defined, thus passing your condition
if (x) return;

// however, when you try to send it as a string, nothing shows up,
// as it is empty. that's why you're getting you're error
console.log(x.toString());
};

example()
```

Comment: No problem; glad I could help :)